# Create a test stripe account that has already completed onboarding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Is there a quick way to create a test account that has already gone through onboarding?

Reason being, I could create a completely new account (e.g. `account = Stripe::Account.create({type: 'express',})` and manually run through the few minutes of account setup to ensure the account has completed onboarding, but that's a little tedious.

Is there any quick way to create a test stripe account that has completed onboarding, but nothing more?

*Example*

Here's ideally what I'd like to do

```rb
# -- some code that creates a test account that has already completed onboarding --
Stripe::Account.create_login_link(account.id)
# the above line should succeed, instead of: 
Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Cannot create a login link for an account that has not completed onboarding.
```

Note: this question happens to use ruby, but my guess is if it's possible in ruby then it's possible in any of the languages in the stripe docs.

**What I know so far**

I checked the [stripe testing docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing) for any reference to account creation with onboarding complete but couldn't spot it

Comment: What about using a fake like https://github.com/thoughtbot/fake_stripe ?

Answer (score 2):

There's unfortunately no way to create a completely onboarded test account through a magic parameter. The only way is to use the test values in the testing docs that you found and pass those in when creating the account.

Comment: It sounds like the testing parameters can be passed in through code? Do you know if all of them can be such that the result is an account with `payments_enabled == True`? If so that would solve the problem (as I’m currently doing it all via the browser which is inefficient)

Comment: For testing purposes, you can create a Custom Connect account via code and pass in all those testing variables: https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create